# variable y dimension in geom_tile ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the values of this datatable:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                            4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
                            2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Counts = c(105L, 6098L, 31L, 388L, 325L, 
                            85L, 105L, 6098L, 31L, 388L, 325L, 85L, 105L, 6098L, 31L, 388L, 
                            325L, 85L, 105L, 6098L, 31L, 388L, 325L, 85L, 105L, 6098L, 31L, 
                            388L, 325L, 85L), variable = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                           "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "T", 
                           "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W"), value = c(0, 
                           0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                           0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Group", "Counts", "variable","value"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))


> head(dt1, 10)
    Group Counts variable value
 1:     1    105        A     0
 2:     2   6098        A     0
 3:     3     31        A     0
 4:     4    388        A     0
 5:     5    325        A     1
 6:     6     85        A     1
 7:     1    105        I     1
 8:     2   6098        I     0
 9:     3     31        I     0
10:     4    388        I     0
```

The data is structured as such: I have 30 groups (in the example data 6) and for each group the value for each variable (A, W, R, I, T) is either 0 or 1. 
What I would like to do is plot the groups, having in the X-Axis the variable name, **in the y axis the cumulative absolute value of the counts variable for each group** and the fill to be equal to the value (so whether the value is 0 or 1).

I have tried the following:

This does not work as I expected (most likely I am missing something obvious but I am very new to plotting)

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x = variable, y = Counts)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(value)))
```

This works as I expected but the problem is that I only get the groups and not the absolute values of the counts:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x = variable, y = Group)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(value)))
```

The group number is continuous so goes from 1-30. But lets take an example where I have 3 (1-3) groups. In each group each variable (A,I,W,R,T) has a value 1 or 0. And each group has a counts value for example group 1 105, group 2 6098 and group 3 31.

What I want is y axis values until 6234 (105 + 6098 + 31) where group 1 variables tiles are spanning from 0-105, group 2 variables tiles from 105-6203 and group 3 variables tiles from 60203-63234. And depending on whether the value is 0 or 1 the tiles have different fill.

I would be very open to other plot suggestions since I am very new at this and I might be missing something.

Comment: please check your  `dput()` output, it's not correct.

Comment: "cumulative value of the counts" - cumulative along what? Just cumulative total along the entire data frame, or cumulated within each `Group` separately, or within each `Group` and `variable` combination?

Comment: For each group, so if group 1 has a counts value of 30 and group 2 has a counts value of 20 I would like to have the y axis equal to 50 and the tiles for group 1 going from 0-30 and the tiles from group 2 from 30-50. I am not really sure I have expressed it perfectly.

Comment: perhaps `ggplot(dt1, aes(x = variable, y = Counts, fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: This is not far from what I want, but is there a way to flag the groups somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m not sure what you want but you can add an interaction term to display the variable per level of value like this:

```
set = interaction(as.factor(dt1$variable):as.factor(dt1$value))
ggplot(dt1, aes(x = set, y = Counts, fill = as.factor(Group))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

**EDIT** plotting by variable x counts with fill = value and ordered by Group

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x = variable, y = Counts, fill = as.factor(value))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity",colour="black",aes(order=as.factor(Group)))
```

Comment: I updated the version, does this make sense? Mind that the bars are the same height given that counts is repeated

Comment: I kept trying with the interaction :) Still not sure what the goal is but maybe this? `dt1$Countslog = log(dt1$Counts)` , if you use Counts the difference will be huge and therefore you cannot see the tiles, followed by:
`ggplot(dt1, aes(variable,Countslog)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=set))`

Comment: No problem :) Yes interaction creates all possible values but only fills when the value is there. From what I understand you want the 'tiles' to extend to different lengths right? This is more a `geom_bar` operation, tiles are commonly of equal length. Also, you have six groups so for variable `A` you have six stacked values, six different colors of which two a different color level (lighter?) given they have `value == 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142692/discussion-between-timfaber-and-user2321).